# SSH passphrase dialog missing

Tags: macos, ssh, ui

I switched from an El Capitan machine to a new MacBook Air with Sierra.
With El Capitan, when I ssh into an host from terminal, the SSH passphrase GUI dialog showed up, and then it never asked again the passphrase for the whole login session.

Now with Sierra the dialog is not showing up, I recurred to adding the following lines to `.bashrc`:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add
```

but the drawback is that every new terminal asks for the passphrase.

How to diagnose the missing dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `ssh-add`, use

```
ssh-add -A
```

This uses the Keychain to find the passphrase, and since your Keychain should be unlocked because you're logged in, you won't be prompted.

(Sierra drastically changed how ssh keys are handled by the OS. The dialog is no more.)

Comment: thanks you for your answer, it says "No identity found in the keychain.". I suppose I need to make "Keychain Access" to know about the keys in my `~/.ssh`, but how?

Comment: @enzotib To add the passphrase to Keychain, run `ssh-add -K` and enter your passphrase.

Comment: OK, I used `ssh-add -K` una tantum to add keys to my keychain, and I only leaved `ssh-add -A` in my .bashrc, and now it seems to work properly, thank you.

Comment: @enzotib Yes, that's correct. If you change your ssh key, you'll need to re-run `ssh-add -K` once to add it to Keychain.