# How do I use ssh agent on MacOS Catalina like OS X El Capitan used to?

Tags: macos, terminal, keychain, ssh

I recently upgraded from OS X El Capitan to MacOS Catalina. I am accustomed to keeping my login session open for an entire week, and I was able to use a passphrase-protected ssh key by entering the passphrase the first time I made an ssh connection, and afterwards the key was acquired from the ssh-agent, without needing to re-enter the passphrase. After shutting down or logging out from my desktop, the key was no longer available (desired behavior).

Is there any way to get similar behavior on MacOS Catalina? I find having to re-enter the passphrase each time I open a new terminal shell undesirable, as setting up an ssh-agent from .bashrc would require.

I would use the answer from [SSH passphrase dialog missing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284713/ssh-passphrase-dialog-missing), but I *do not* want to store my passphrase in the keychain.

Comment: Why have a passphrase if you're going to leave the session open for a week?  Just use an SSH key without a passphrase

Comment: @Allan The passphrase is to protect the *key*. It's one thing for someone to use my identity (temporarily) in the unlikely event someone gains access to the desktop/laptop while the session is open. It's another altogether that someone might obtain the _key itself_ and compromise my identity, possibly without my knowing it.